# Which algorithm use sorted method in Stream interface

Tags: java, sorting, stream

When I print the values in the sorted method,

```
Stream.of("d", "a", "b", "e", "c", "f")
    .sorted((s1, s2) -> {
        System.out.printf("sort: %s - %s\n", s1, s2);
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output is as follows;

```
sort: a - d
sort: b - a
sort: b - d
sort: b - a
sort: e - b
sort: e - d
sort: c - d
sort: c - b
sort: f - c
sort: f - e
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I could not understand the logic of the sorting algorithm here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hm interesting that it compared `b - a` twice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer below is relevant to OpenJDK (checked against 10.0.1).

Streams delegate the sorting operations to the relevant `Arrays.sort` methods (see `end` methods of various `SortingOps`).

## Sorting streams of objects

For sorting objects, `TimSort` (basically a merge sort which uses insertion sort when the divisions of the input are small enough) is the preferred method.

The authors credit [Tim Peter's implementation of list sort in Python as an inspiration](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt), further attributing the idea to the paper `"Optimistic Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", Peter McIlroy, SODA (Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms), 467-474, Austin, Texas, 25-27 January 1993`.

However the user can also request `MergeSort` (falling back to insertion sort when the arrays are small enough - in OpenJDK 10 it's 32 or fewer elements) to be used by setting the `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` property to `true`. This is planned to be removed in future releases.

## Sorting streams of primitives

For sorting streams of primitives (`byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`) - dual pivot quicksort is implemented. The authors (Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Josh Bloch) do not give any more information about where the inspiration came from.

## Sources

To learn more, see OpenJDK code:

- [SortedOps.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/SortedOps.java) - implementation relevant to the streams
- [Arrays.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java) - implementation of the `Arrays` helper, see the different `sort` methods
- [TimSort.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) - implementation of TimSort
- [ComparableTimSort.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ComparableTimSort.java) - variation for classes implementing `Comparable`
- [DualPivotQuicksort.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java) - implementation of sorting for primitives

Comment: Very interesting algorithm. I will research the algorithm now :)

Comment: While I am trying to do a test I am always finding stream.sorted faster  
for(int i = 0;i < 10000;i++) {
   
   
   arr[i] = (int) Math.random();
  }
  
  
  IntStream stream1 = Arrays.stream(arr);
  long sttime = System.nanoTime();
  Arrays.sort(arr);
  long endtime = System.nanoTime();
  long sttime1 = System.nanoTime(); 
  stream1.sorted();
  long endtime1 = System.nanoTime();
 

  
  System.out.println(sttime - endtime);
  
  

  System.out.println(sttime1 - endtime1);
Not sure why if you know can you please elaborate