# Working of sorted() in java streams using lambda expression as comparator

Tags: sorting, java-8, java-stream, comparator, lambda

I have the following code:

```
        Stream.of("5", "1", "3", "4", "2", "6")
        .sorted((s1, s2) -> {
            System.out.printf("sort: %s; %s\n", s1, s2);
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        })
        .forEach(s -> System.out.println("forEach: " + s));
```

where I am trying to sort the given elements in a custom order defined by lambda expression above in the code.
The code works as expected. No surprises there. 
But I am curious on how the sorted() works on my provided lambda.
I put a print statement inside sorted() and I see following result:

```
sort: 3; 1
sort: 3; 5
sort: 3; 1
sort: 4; 3
sort: 4; 5
sort: 2; 4
sort: 2; 3
sort: 2; 1
sort: 6; 3
sort: 6; 5
forEach: 1
forEach: 2
forEach: 3
forEach: 4
forEach: 5
forEach: 6
```

and this is not what I expected. 
I see that 3 and 1 are compared twice. Why ? 
I see that 6 is never compared with 1 2 and 4. Why again ?

I cannot deduce any logic in this way of comparison.

Did some research and learnt that sorted() uses merge sort internally. For given array merge sort will require 6 comparisons:

```
2  6
4  6
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

but above we see way more than 6 comparisons. So what is happening ? 
In general how does sort() work with custom comparator ?

Comment: Comparing every number with ever other mean *quadratic time complexity* which is what elaborated algorithms try to avoid. As a side effect, it may contain redundant comparisons in some scenarios which still is way more efficient than every element with every other, especially with larger data sets.

Comment: Duplicate. You can find answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943309/which-algorithm-use-sorted-method-in-stream-interface

Comment: Thanks @AmanShivhare, for bringing the original to my notice.

Comment: Looking at original answer my take away is that the inbuilt algo that it use is not efficient for small number of elements but it is significantly better for large number of elements. Did I conclude correctly ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @AmanSoni Try different many set then decide which one is efficient. (for small case)